# Gaussian integers: Proof that if $N(\alpha) = N(\beta)$ then $\alpha = t \beta, t \in \{1, -1, i, -i \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

I need to prove that for $\alpha, \beta$ Gaussian integers:
$$N(\alpha) = N(\beta)\Leftrightarrow \alpha = t\beta, t \in \{-1, 1, i, -i\}$$
Now I have found out that if $\alpha = t\beta \Rightarrow N(\alpha) = N(t \beta) = N(t)N(\beta) = 1 N(\beta) = N(\beta).$

How do I prove the other way around?

Comment: It's not true. Consider $\alpha = 2+i,\, \beta = 2-i$.

Comment: Just agreeing with Daniel. The statement is false - it's not "if and only if."

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer it is indeed not true.

Comment: And in case you are tempted to think "then $\alpha = t\beta$ or $\alpha = t\cdot \overline{\beta}$" might save it, consider $\alpha = (2+i)(3+i)$ and $\beta = (2-i)(3+i)$.